# Angular Passing observable as input parameter to child compoent

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a parent component with multiple children that share the same complicated data object (D3js graph data). Each child can update the D3js object, but the change has to be reflected in the other child components.

I was thinking of putting this D3js object as an observable in a shared service, but I would like the ability to reuse the child components and pass them different data independent of each other. Should I pass an observable as an input variable into the child components?

Since updating the D3js object will be quite complex, it doesn't make sense to use an EventEmitter to update the parent. Is there a 'best practices' way to implement this scenario?

Comment: As  far as I understood, your object has singleton nature, so the best practice here is to create a shared service as API to your object management. I would generally avoid using such complex data in input/output mechanism.

Comment: These child components are charts that will share data. But say I have a list of charts that all share data but one. That chart has a different source of data. With a shared service implementing this would be difficult because the service will be difficult to change in the child components. Where as passing the data as input variables makes it easy to have independent data. Does this make sense?

Comment: Still you could utilize smth like ChartService and built it in scalable API way, so it could control the state of all chart data in your app. This gives you mechanism for dynamic script injection in the DOM, initing charts, fetching data if needed and more - your class encapsulates whole chart logics. Whoever reads your code will thank you, as future yourself as well :)

Comment: I'm not really understanding. How could the ChartService compensate for a dynamic number of charts with some sharing data, some not? By sharing data I mean when one updates the others update.  I would think that the get chart data will either have to be hardcoded (which kills the dynamic nature) or there needs to be a lookup for each distinct chart data that the components would access. In the latter you would need to index the correct data in the child chart component.